number of selfie photos different after iPhone migration
I migrated from an phone 12 pro max to an iPhone 16 pro. Both phones are on iOS 18.0.1.
I used the quick start method where you scan the orb.
After migration, the count of videos, live photos, and portrait photos were exactly the same.
However, the count for selfies was 3080 on the old phone and 2885 on the new phone. I also noticed that the "shared with you" section appears on the old phone but not the new phone. Though if I individually look for those photos I can find them.
I visually compared the two folders for discrepancies. On the old phone, if someone sent an attachment in a message, and it was categorized as a selfie, it shows up in the selfies folder. I specifically looked for those images on the new phone. They still exist but are not being placed in the selfies folder.
This makes me nervous that photos are not perfectly synced but is this maybe just a known bug in the way that photos are categorized? I would like to confirm that I'm still saving all photos from message attachments.

I can imagine that some selfie photos lost the "selfie" category due to the migration. This is of course not desirable! But to see whether all photos were migrated, you can compare the total number of photos/videos on your old device and your newly migrated device. If the number matches, no photos should have been lost.
However, what surprises me, is that there is no "selfie" category visible on icloud.com, as there is on all devices (iPhone, iPad, Mac). See also this question in apple discussion
